# Docky have stopped working since update

Tags: 10.10, 64-bit, docky

I'm using the Docky ppa, and since the latest update it won't start. If I run it from the terminal, this is what I get:

```
[Info  09:21:19.005] Docky version: 2.1.0 bzr docky r1761 ppa
[Info  09:21:19.024] Kernel version: 2.6.35.24
[Info  09:21:19.026] CLR version: 2.0.50727.1433
[Debug 09:21:19.493] [UserArgs] BufferTime = 0
[Debug 09:21:19.494] [UserArgs] MaxSize = 2147483647
[Debug 09:21:19.494] [UserArgs] NetbookMode = False
[Debug 09:21:19.494] [UserArgs] NoPollCursor = False
[Debug 09:21:19.528] [SystemService] Using org.freedesktop.UPower for battery information
[Info  09:21:19.564] [ThemeService] Setting theme: Transparent
[Debug 09:21:19.587] [DesktopItemService] Loading remap file '/usr/share/docky/remaps.ini'.
[Debug 09:21:19.599] [DesktopItemService] Remapping 'Picasa3.exe' to 'picasa'.
[Debug 09:21:19.599] [DesktopItemService] Remapping 'nbexec' to 'netbeans'.
[Debug 09:21:19.599] [DesktopItemService] Remapping 'deja-dup-preferences' to 'deja-dup'.
[Debug 09:21:19.599] [DesktopItemService] Remapping 'VirtualBox' to 'virtualbox'.
[Warn  09:21:19.600] [DesktopItemService] Could not find remap file '/home/lasse/.local/share/docky/remaps.ini'!
[Debug 09:21:19.602] [DesktopItemService] Loading desktop item cache '/home/lasse/.cache/docky/docky.desktop.en_DK.utf8.cache'.
[Info  09:21:20.101] [DockServices] Dock services initialized.
[Debug 09:21:20.134] [DBusManager] DBus Registered: org.gnome.Docky
[Debug 09:21:20.142] [DBusManager] DBus Registered: net.launchpad.DockManager
Stacktrace:

  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.IO.MonoIO.Read (intptr,byte[],int,int,System.IO.MonoIOError&) <IL 0x00012, 0x00062>
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.IO.MonoIO.Read (intptr,byte[],int,int,System.IO.MonoIOError&) <IL 0x00012, 0x00062>
  at System.IO.FileStream.ReadData (intptr,byte[],int,int) <IL 0x00009, 0x00047>
  at System.IO.FileStream.RefillBuffer () <IL 0x0001c, 0x0002b>
  at System.IO.FileStream.ReadByte () <IL 0x00079, 0x000c7>
  at Mono.Addins.Serialization.BinaryXmlReader.ReadNext () <IL 0x0000b, 0x00031>
  at Mono.Addins.Serialization.BinaryXmlReader.Skip () <IL 0x0003c, 0x00053>
  at Mono.Addins.Serialization.BinaryXmlReader.Skip () <IL 0x00047, 0x0005f>
  at Mono.Addins.Serialization.BinaryXmlReader.Skip () <IL 0x00047, 0x0005f>
```

And this .Skip () continues infinitely, and very fast.
I've tried cleaning the cache and reinstalling docky, but without luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are experiencing [bug #661495](https://bugs.launchpad.net/docky/+bug/661495).

The fix is in the first [comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/docky/+bug/661495/comments/1):

```
Do this: rm -Rf ~/.local/share/docky/plugins

Then start Docky.
```